# Creating and overriding an interface being put into a parameter

Tags: c#, function, dynamic, parameters, interface

Currently I'm converting code from Java to C# and using a function:

```
        eventManager.Listen(typeof(EntityCreateEvent), 
        new EntityCreateListener()
        {
            public override void Create(Entity Entity)
            {
                //add(entity);
            }
        });
```

The problem is that, this is far from legal in C#. How do I go about doing this in C#? I'd prefer not to do a work-around as I have quite a few of these in the code I'm changing that have stuff in the override that needs to be dynamic.

Comment: I don't see any interface in this code...

Comment: I'm sorry, the interface is "EntityCreateListener()"

Comment: @Claies - this is Java syntax. `EntityCreateListener` is an abstract base class, and here he has created a new implementation inline. It's a cool thing you can do in Java which you can't do in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are creating an event listener.

Java provides anonymous interfaces as a way to subscribe to events.

C# doesn't have anonymous interfaces. However, there is an event framework baked into the language.

So instead of exposing a `Listen` method on `EventManager`, expose an event:

```
 class EntityCreatedEventArgs : EventArgs
 {
      public Entity Entity {get; set; }
 }

 class EventManager
 {
      public event EventHandler<EntityCreatedEventArgs> EntityCreate;


      private void FireCreateEvent(Entity entity)
      {
          if(this.EntityCreate)
          {
               this.EntityCreate(this, new EntityCreatedEventArgs { Entity = entity });
          }
      }
      // Rest of implementation
 }
```

Then your listening class can 'subscribe' to this event

```
 public class OtherThing
 {
       public OtherThing(EventManager eventManager)
       {
           eventManager.EntityCreate += this.EventManager_EntityCreate;
       }

       void EventManager_EntityCreate(object sender, EntityCreatedEventArgs args)
       {
       }
 }
```